# Bigquery : What is the difference between service account json file and application default credentials json file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am curious to know if there is any difference between the service account json file and application default credentials json file (GCP)?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that one is a credential and the other is a strategy to locate credentials.

Service Account Credentials are the recommended method of authorizing Google API requests. These credentials are stored in a file (JSON or P12). However, when running under some services such as Compute Engine, credentials are automatically created for the instance and are made avilable via the metadata server.

Application Default Credentials (ADC) will search for credentails.

1. If the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is set, ADC will use the file for credentials that the variable points to.
2. If the variable is not set, then the default service account will be used if running on Compute Engine, App Engine, Kubernetes Engine or Cloud Functions.

If the previous two steps fail to find valid credentials, ADC will fail and an error occurs.

Using the environment variable to specify Service Account credentials:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/mysecretpath/service_account.json"
```

ADC will automatically load the credentials from `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

Loading credentials from json (Python example):

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        '/mysecretpath/service_account.json')
```

Loading service account default credentials on Compute Engine:

```
from google.auth import compute_engine
from google.cloud import storage
credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```

Loading service account default credentials on App Engine:

```
from google.auth import app_engine
from google.cloud import storage
credentials = app_engine.Credentials()
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```

And so on for Kubernetes, Cloud Functions, etc.

ADC uses similar methods to create credentials using the above examples.

The example uses the ADC strategy to locate credentials:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
```

There is another common method to obtain credentials. These are `End User Credentials` that are derived from an `OAuth 2.0 Flow`. These credentials require that you setup Client Secrets Credentials that are used to authorize User Credentials. This is the method to obtain credentials from a user account such as [Google Accounts](https://account.google.com/).

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#end_user_authentication_example) will provide more details.